# How to Read the Crash Report file in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to Read my wp8  crash report file to solve the bugs.

I want to solve the Crashes but not able to read the crashes and also not able to read where the crash occurs

Comment: anyone who have read crash report ?